# Zapier to WordPress upload manipulate

Tags: wordpress, zapier

Is there any way i can manipulate action from to zapier to wordpress ?zapier is uploading files to my wordpress media and i did not want to go files to media but on my custom folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Behind the scenes, we're doing a call to [wp.uploadFile](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Media#wp.uploadFile). It uploads to your default media location, which you can configure by following instructions provided in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29936/can-i-upload-media-to-a-specific-folder).

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks for the help i will let you know if i need more help on zapier

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).